# prove a finite limit exists

Tags: calculus

> Let $f$ be differentiable for any $x$. 
>   Given that
>   $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x) = 0,$$
>   prove there exists a finite $L$ such that
>   $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=L.$$

---

By definition:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x)
   = \lim_{x\to \infty} \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=0$$

also:

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} x = x_0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to x_0} (x-x_0)=0
    \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to \infty} \lim_{x\to x_0}(x-x_0)
                     =\lim_{x\to \infty} 0 = 0$$

Therefore,

$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{x\to \infty} \lim_{x\to x_0} (x-x_0)
    &\cdot \lim_{x\to \infty} \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \\
 &=\lim_{x\to \infty} \lim_{x\to x_0}(x-x_0)
    \cdot \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\\
 &=\lim_{x\to \infty} \lim_{x\to x_0}(x-x_0)\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \\
 &=\lim_{x\to \infty} \lim_{x\to x_0}{f(x)-f(x_0)}=0
\end{split} $$

$f$ is differentiable therefore is continuous at any $x$, which by definition:

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) =f(x_0)
    \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to \infty}\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x_0)$$

this where I got....i'm losing my mind....

Comment: What about $f(x) = \ln x$...? Where did you get this exercise?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi a h.w. assignment. and lnx isnt differentiable at any x

Answer (score 4):

The statement is false. Consider $f(x)=\log x$ (any basis $>1$ will do).

This is not defined for all $x$, but it's easy to make the example for a function defined for all $x$ and differentiable.

Comment: gotcha....i think x^(1/3) will do.....thanks a lot!

Comment: @Rubenz Well, this is not differentiable at $0$. Just consider $\log x$ for $x\ge1$ and define the function for $x<1$ as the tangent to the logarithm at $1$.